# Got some troubles with using OneHotEncoder to multiple categories

Tags: scikit-learn, pipelines, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to get the final pipeline on the titanic dataset(Example was taken from the 'Hands-on ML' book).

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder, LabelBinarizer

num_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('selector', DataFrameSelector(list(df_num))),
    ('imputer',SimpleImputer(strategy='median', fill_value='num',missing_values=np.nan)),
    ('std_scaler',StandardScaler())
])
cat_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('selector', DataFrameSelector(list(df_cat))),
    ('imputer',SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent', fill_value='categorical',missing_values=np.nan)),
    ('cat_encoder', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)),
])
```

```
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion


full_pipeline = FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[
        ("num_pipeline", num_pipeline),
        ("cat_pipeline", cat_pipeline),
    ])

df_prepared = full_pipeline.fit_transform(df)
df_prepared.shape
df_total = pd.DataFrame(df_prepared, columns=df.columns)
df_total
```

Where

```
df_num = ['Pclass', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Fare']
df_cat = ['Sex', 'Embarked']
```

The problem is that I got the ValueError:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (668, 10), indices imply (668, 7)
```

I tried dropping  `'Embarked'`  from the `df_cat`
and it created the DF somehow(but it was inaccurate). I assume it didn't work because of `'Embarked'`
had 3 categories(10-3 = 7 - that's the number of columns I wanted.)

If I drop `'Sex'`
category, I get `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (668, 8), indices imply (668, 7)` (10-2=8)

How to encode all two categories using `Pipeline()`
and which wrong steps I've made?

Answer (score 1):

`df.columns` is incorrect because after One-hot-encoding you have more columns with different names. In your example instead of `Sex` you have two columns for the actual values and instead of `Embarked` you have three.

The whole point of the pipeline is to create those additional columns so why do you want to drop them? I do not know where you define `df.columns` but it seems to me the error is happening in this line:

```py
df_total = pd.DataFrame(df_prepared, columns=df.columns)
```